# Running a background thread not working

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to run -getHTMLupdate in background but it's not working.

-viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *navBarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menubar.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 15, 5, 15)];//Navbar
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getHTMLupdate) withObject:nil];
}
```

Here's -getHTMLupdate

```
-(void) getHTMLupdate {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    /* set headers, etc. on request if needed */
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appstarme.com/GD/GDHTMLPARSINGINFORMATION.php"]];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];
    NSString *token = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<h1>" intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"</h1>" intoString:&token];

    NSLog(@"DATA : %@", html);

    _updateFromUser.text = html;
```

Here's the console output

```
   2013-07-02 20:26:25.775 Social App[8130:3707] DATA : 
Please check out the new Skype contest at www.Skype.com
2013-07-02 20:26:25.776 Social App[8130:3707] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1e8ab970: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x3a021259 WebThreadLock
2   0x36083185 <redacted>
3   0xc75fd -[homeChannel getHTMLupdate]
4   0x349e7231 <redacted>
5   0x3c2170e1 <redacted>
6   0x3c216fa8 thread_start
```

The NSLog oddly returns the correct data but the app still crashes

EDIT

Added this at the end of the code

```
[_updateFromUser performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setText:)
                            withObject: html
                         waitUntilDone: FALSE];
```

worked perfectly.

Comment: You are not supposed to change any UI stuff outside the main thread!

In the last line of you getHTMLupdate you do, is this the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're crashing because you're trying to update the UI in the background thread with this call:

```
_updateFromUser.text = html;
```

I would suggest leveraging the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and update your UI when the`connection:didReceiveData:` method fires...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];
  NSString *token = nil;
  [scanner scanUpToString:@"<h1>" intoString:NULL];
  [scanner scanUpToString:@"</h1>" intoString:&token];

  NSLog(@"DATA : %@", html);

  _updateFromUser.text = html;
}
```

[Apple Docs Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

EDIT: I'd also recommend you change your request to `sendAsynchronousRequest` in order to not bother spawning a background thread as well as take advantage of the delegate method as intended.

EDIT2: I messed up... I had the delegate wrong... Forgot which one was deprecated in iOS5. Use `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. Answer above has been addressed.

Comment: I tried using 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"got data");
}

but it never returned anything

Comment: Did you add the delegate to your .h file?

Comment: Edited delegate... My mistake. Use NSURLConnectionDataDelegate